# invalid literal with int base 10 for only one input in list, when all others work (postfix)

Tags: python

```
expr = '5 3 -'

lyst = ['4', '5 7 +', '7 5 *', '5 3 -', '5 5 /', '8 5 * 3 +', '8 5 3 + *', '8 3 5 * + 7 -', '8 3 + 5 6 - *', '8 3 + 2 7 - *', '8 3 + 2 * 7 -', '8 5 * 3 2 - 7 3 * - +', '8 5 * 3 + 7 - 5 3 * -', '7 9 * 7 + 5 6 * - 3 + 4 -']

def eval_postfix(expr):
    import re
    token_list = re.split("([^0-9])", expr)
    stack = Stack()
    for token in token_list:
        if token == "" or token == " ":
            continue
        if token == "+":
            sum = stack.pop() + stack.pop()
            stack.push(sum)
        elif token == "*":
            product = stack.pop() * stack.pop()
            stack.push(product)
        else:
            stack.push(int(token))
    return stack.pop()
print(eval_postfix(expr))
```

So i have this list of postfix expressions, and i am trying to evaluate it.

All of the inputs work, except for the '5 3 -' input. It is pulling a invalid literal for int base 10. Now i know this error is usually when something recieves something that is not supposed to be an integer, but this doesn't seeem to be the case.

```
stack.push(int(token))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

any help or insight would be very helpful.

Comment: Add `print(token)` before the line where you get that error and you'll solve it yourself within seconds. But as a guess, it doesn't appear that you have any code to handle subtraction, so it's trying to parse "-" as a number.

Comment: a little confused because it just display this: 5
3
-

Comment: `int('-')` raises an error, yes. You cannot convert `-` to an int. Do you mean to be handling this operator with something like `elif token == "-"` ?

Comment: then why does 5 7 + work?

Comment: `5 7 +` works because when your code gets to the `+` character, it sums the top two elements of the stack. It does not conver `+` to an int. But when it gets to `-` it tries to convert it to an int. Do you want calculate the difference of the top two stack elements when you get to `-` ?

Comment: yes i do want to do that

Comment: Your function doesnt handle subtraction and division. Please add elif conditions for - and /

Answer (score 0):

Converting `-` to an int will raise an error.

```py
>>> int('-')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '-'
```

So you can fix your code by handling `-` as another operator. You are already doing so for `+` and `*`, so it is just another condition to check for. Remember that the subtraction operands come off the stack out of order!

```py
expr = '5 3 -'

lyst = ['4', '5 7 +', '7 5 *', '5 3 -', '5 5 /', '8 5 * 3 +', '8 5 3 + *', '8 3 5 * + 7 -', '8 3 + 5 6 - *', '8 3 + 2 7 - *', '8 3 + 2 * 7 -', '8 5 * 3 2 - 7 3 * - +', '8 5 * 3 + 7 - 5 3 * -', '7 9 * 7 + 5 6 * - 3 + 4 -']

def eval_postfix(expr):
    import re
    token_list = re.split("([^0-9])", expr)
    stack = Stack()
    for token in token_list:
        if token == "" or token == " ":
            continue
        if token == "+":
            sum = stack.pop() + stack.pop()
            stack.push(sum)
        elif token == "*":
            product = stack.pop() * stack.pop()
            stack.push(product)
        # extra condition here to handle subtraction
        elif token == "-":
            second_operand = stack.pop()
            difference = stack.pop() - second_operand
            stack.push(difference)
        else:
            print(token)
            stack.push(int(token))
    return stack.pop()
print(eval_postfix(expr))
```

It still does not not handle `/`, but this can be solved in the same way as subtraction.

Comment: Why 3 - 5 for "5 3 -"?

Comment: For the expression `5 3 -`, they are inserted into the stack like `[5, 3]`. So if you do `stack.pop() - stack.pop()` it pops the top element first, and then the element beneath, which would look like `3 - 5`. But we want `5 - 3` (I assume `5 3 -` should be `5 - 3`). So to handle this situation we pop the top element first, then add it as the second operand, whereas it would have been the first. You only have to do this for subtraction and division because order matters.